# How can i debug/diagnose program crash during initialisation?

Tags: c++

One of our programs has an issue: it is crashing during initialisation, before entering the main function.

How can i determine the reason for that?

When the issue has arisen before, it was eventually fixed by removing any heap memory allocation from static objects. Is there any way to check if this is going on?

Comment: Use `valgrind` or `gdb`.

Comment: This could be dependency mismatch or missing libraries. On which platform this program runs?

Comment: On stretch. Regretfully, that means valgrind/gdb aren't directly applicable. However, i can run it on linux or windows to determine whether heap usage before `main` is going on.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Stretch environment, but most linkers will output a map file (`*.map`) which will show where code sections are loaded into memory. If you have the address of the crash, you may be able to lookup the crashing function in the mapfile. That may give you a clue.